# 16.04 LTS - Problem with the installation of texlive-full

Tags: 16.04, texlive

I tried to install texlive-full in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS by

`sudo apt-get install texlive-full`

. I got the following message

`E: Dépendances non satisfaites. Essayez « apt-get -f install » sans paquet
(ou indiquez une solution).`

saying that some dependencies are not satisfied. Then I tried

`sudo apt-get -f install`

and I got the following error

`dpkg: erreur de traitement de l'archive /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-fonts-extra-doc_2017.20171004-1~16.04.york0_all.deb (--unpack) :
 tentative de remplacement de « /usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/mweights/README », qui appartient aussi au paquet texlive-latex-extra-doc 2015.20160320-1
dpkg-deb : erreur : le sous-processus coller a été tué par le signal (Relais brisé (pipe))
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-fonts-extra-doc_2017.20171004-1~16.04.york0_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

but I'm unsure what it exactly means. A solution would be very welcome.

Comment: It is a conflict between packages, the REAMDE conflicts between those 2 packages. Best to file a bug report, but you can probably `sudo mv /usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/mweights/README /usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/mweights/README.mweights` and try again `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: Doesn't seem like an Ubuntu bug: The newer package is from a PPA or  other non-Ubuntu source. Stop using that source, and notify the source maintainer that they are distributing a package that causes errors.

Comment: @Panther, I tried the commands you advised, but the same error happened.

Comment: @user535733, can you point out the official source ?

Comment: If those commands failed you will have to file a bug report.